# IoC and Azure / SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4, inversion-of-control, unity-container, azure-table-storage

Question that is the basis for this one: [Alternative to Windows Azure tables out of the cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695041/alternative-to-windows-azure-tables-out-of-the-cloud)

In the answer, inversion of control is mentioned as a way to decouple the explicit dependency on Azure Storage Tables and a nameless solution. If I'm using Unity and Entity Framework (if that matters), would it be possible to have an either/or solution with AST and SQL Server 2008? If so, are there any write ups for achieving this?

Comment: What are you trying to inject?  The database connection information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to code against an interface. The implementation of which is hooked by via the configuration of the container. The implementation could then either be a SQL Server concrete class or an ATS concrete class.